# Generate animation again by clicking on a button using ng-class. Angular.js

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I have an animation that runs only once. I would like to click on the button to repeat the animation. I do not know what I'm doing wrong. thank you very much.

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
 <div class='contendor_portafolio' class='next'>
 <video  id='video' width="320" height="240" ng-class='transicion' controls>
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
 </video>
</div>
<button ng-click="fn_transicion()">again</button>
```

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
 function MyCtrl($scope) {
 $scope.fn_transicion= function(sentido){
        $scope.transicion="next";
 }
}
  #video{
     width: 98%;
     height: 100%;
     transition: all linear 0.5s;
     background:blue;
     -webkit-animation: next 1s 1; /* Safari 4+ */
  }

  @-webkit-keyframes next {
     25% { 
        -webkit-transform: translateX(1700px);
     }
     50% { 
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-2000px);
        display: none;
     }
     60% { 
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-1700px);
     }
     100%{
     } 
  }
```

I need use ng-class.

http://jsfiddle.net/wmvfx5cd/

Answer (score 1):

Add css to one class and example `.run-animation` , add and remove it on click of the button

```
$scope.fn_transicion= function(sentido){
    $scope.transicion="next";
        var el = document.getElementById('video');
    // -> removing the class
    el.classList.remove("run-animation");
    void el.offsetWidth;
    // -> and re-adding the class
    el.classList.add("run-animation");
}
```

**[Check the working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/saidulu401/wmvfx5cd/1/)**

**Updated Answer:**
Using ng-class

**HTML**:

```
 <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div class='contendor_portafolio' class='next'>
    <video  id='video' width="320" height="240" ng-class="{'run-animation': transicion === true}" controls>
        <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
  </div>
  <button ng-click="fn_transicion()">again</button>
</div>
```

**JS**:

```
 var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.controller("MyCtrl", ['$scope','$timeout',
function($scope,$timeout) {
$scope.transicion=true;
    $scope.fn_transicion= function(sentido){
        $scope.transicion=false;
      $timeout(function() {
        $scope.transicion=true;
      }, 100);
    }

}]);
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/saidulu401/wmvfx5cd/3/)**

Comment: Is more or less what I want, but I need to use if or if, the ng-class. This is a small problem I had in my real project.

Comment: Not as I wished. I need to do this using ng-class.